# Textjoin with if(and) function

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have this formula which works fine :

`=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A4:$E4<=9,$A4:$E4,"")),"")`

When I try this formula with AND() function, I can't get the result I want:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(AND($A4:$E4>=10,$A4:$E4<=25),$A4:$E4,"")),"")
```

Something I am doing wrong, or Textjoin doesn't work with If(and()) functions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using ***+*** rather than the ***AND()*** function.

Comment: I don't have this function in my Excel but my primary guess would be the AND part which will not return ARRAY.

Comment: Really Excel 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array formulas do not like `AND` or `OR` use `*` or `+` respectively.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(($A4:$E4>=10)*($A4:$E4<=25),$A4:$E4,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.